# Simple jQuery $.get example code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the output of a webpage and I found that jQuery has a method for doing this through the [$.get method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

From the link above, I found the following example code:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

I modified the example code to the following:

```
$.get('http://www.google.com', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

But it doesn't work. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6WQqD/1/

What am I doing wrong? How can I make a simple HTTP request that outputs the content of the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites.

Comment: Best practice for this is to create a server side script which will call the API/url you want to call and then create an ajax script which will `$.get` YOUR script (which in turn does the get to the external url) and returns the output. :)

Answer (score 0):

For cross-domain request you can use one of the following approaches:

**1** JSONP 
It requires the server part supports jsonp (contains specific code for crossdomain requests). 
For GET requests try use dataType = jsonp in ajax settings:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "other-domain-url",
 type: 'GET',
 crossDomain: true,
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 jsonpCallback:'callback',
 cache: false
});
```

You should specify callback function to be executing after the response is retrieved. Response will be passed as a parameter.

**2** Use transparently proxy on the server part of your site. Configurate proxy (e.g. nginx) to redirect necessary local requests to other domain.
So in js you will use local ajax:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/local",
     type: 'GET'
}
```

and in config you should use proxy settings:

```
location /local {       
            proxy_pass http://other-domain-url
        }
```